# Display RSVP data from multiple AJAX calls in Template Ember

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I have been trying to render data from a RSVP call to my template but for some reason I cant get it to work, Ember Console shows my data in the model section but nothing is shown to the user....

My idea is to get data from a few APIs and render it in the template "The Ember Way" not sure what I'm missing.

This is how my my code looks so far:

My Model:

```
model: function(params) {
  var articles = [];
  var promises = {
    nyt: Ember.$.getJSON('THE URL GOES HERE'),
    reddit: Ember.$.getJSON('THE URL GOES HERE')
  };

  Ember.RSVP.hash(promises).then(function(results) {
    var nytFeed    = results.nyt.response.docs;
    var redditFeed = results.reddit.data.children;

    Ember.$.each(nytFeed, function(){
      articles.push({
        'url': this.web_url,
        'description': this.snippet,
        'news-type': this.section_name,
        'date': this.pub_date,
        'title': this.main
      });
    });

    Ember.$.each(redditFeed, function(){
      articles.push({
        'url': this.url,
        'description': this.url,
        'news-type': this.subreddit,
        'date': this.created_utc,
        'title': this.data.title
      });
    });
    // console.log(articles);
  });
  return articles;
}
```

And Template:

```
<p>Feed</p>
{{#each item in model}}
    <p>Is this working?</p>
    <h2><p>{{item.title}}</p></h2>
    <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    <p>{{item.news-type}}</p>
    <p>{{item.date}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: replace `push` with `pushObject`, example https://emberjs.jsbin.com/dubocifofu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You also could block your model hook with your promise (by returning the promise) and return the collection from inside of the promise, but I like magical feel of the page rendering faster and pieces coming in as they show up.

Comment: @melc That worked! thanks a lot for the quick reply, also what do you think  about that approach, parsing the data in the model and the sending it to the template? Would it be better to parse it in the controller instead?

Comment: @AndresRoget it is fine and i agree with the pov of @Kingpin2k. It is preferable to prepare the model in routes and place logic related to the application state and events in the controllers. Also consider moving the logic in `setupController` if you ever need access to both the controller and model.